# Animate tabBox in shiny or shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In a `shiny` app I wanted to include an animated `tabBox`, similar to animated `sliderInput` - after specified time the tab would automatically switch to the next one. This doesn't seem to be an option in `tabBox`. I tried two solutions, neither worked. First I tried to simply link animation from `sliderInput` to `tabBox`:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sliderInput(inputId = "slider", label = "Player", min = 1, max = 4, value = 1,
                animate = animationOptions(interval = 1000, loop = TRUE)),
    textOutput(outputId = "text")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabBox(
      id="tabbox",
        tabPanel(title = 1),
        tabPanel(title = 2),
        tabPanel(title = 3),
        tabPanel(title = 4)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$text <- renderText({paste0("tabbox: ", input$tabbox, " slider: ",input$slider, " reactive: ", A$a)})
  A <- reactiveValues(a = 1)
  observeEvent(
    input$slider,
    A$a <- input$slider
    updateTabItems(session = session, inputId = "tabbox", selected = A$a)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

However, this code only changes the reactive value `A$a`, but doesn't change `input$tabbox` (`A$a` is there only so I could see which step fails).

The second solution I tried was to run this function on button click, but it also failed:

```
for(i in 1:4){
  Sys.sleep(2)
  updateTabItems(session = session, inputId = "tabbox", selected = i)
}
```

Questions:

Is it possible by just using R? How could it be done?

Comment: This can probably be done with javascript. I will try and submit an answer

Comment: `updateTabItems` is for updating `tabItem` not `tabBox` or `tabPanel`